# TP Link router respond to ping but admin page times out

Tags: networking, router, ping, telnet, timeout

I have TP Link router with an access point attached to it to extend bandwidth over the entire house. I did this setup around 5 years back at my family's house which works perfect to this point. However I am trying to log in to admin page of the router but I am facing a connection timeout issue.

I made sure the Gateway address is the same I am using in the browser and with telnet command

```
personal-nizar:~ NizarYousri$ route get default
   route to: default
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0


personal-nizar:~ NizarYousri$ telnet -d 192.168.1.1 80
Trying 192.168.1.1...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.1: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I forgot to mention that I am able to ping the IP without a problem

```
personal-nizar:~ NizarYousri$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.941 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=2.759 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=2.782 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.941/2.161/2.782/0.862 ms
personal-nizar:~ NizarYousri$
```

EDIT

Here's ifconfig result below

```
ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:95:45:56  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d1d8:71bf:d733:3a68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20801 errors:0 dropped:16 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3584758 (3.4 MiB)  TX bytes:2172686 (2.0 MiB)
```

[And this is the user's guide for the very router](http://static.tp-link.com/resources/software/201161016042811.pdf)

[http://192.168.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khKt8.png)

I am using a wired connection to straight to the router.

Obviously my goal is to be able to get the login page for my router. I really appreciate your assistance folks

Comment: Yes correct - into the LAN

Comment: Have you tried rebooting it and keep refreshing the web browser while it's booting? Try keeping the IP gateway blank so no gateway and just be sure the subnet mask is correct and the IP is not duplicate too just in case. It should still be able to access it on the same subnet without gateway.

Comment: Yeap - just did that. Same result.

Comment: Do you have tons of configurations on that thing? Just curious how catastrophic a factory reset would be if that's even an option in your case. I assume you have no recent configuration backups where you could wipe and then push the config?

Comment: How many LAN ports does this thing have by chance? I know on some routers you can setup restriction to just allow admin access on one specific LAN port too so think about that and eliminate that if you have time to do so.

Comment: @ITSnuggles factory reset is still an option to consider; I just have to pick the right time to do so. Regarding the LAN ports I only have 4. I will try all four of them and will let you know the results

Comment: Also, are you aware of some network troubleshooting steps that I may follow which may isolate the issue in someway?

Answer (score 1):

From [recent experience with picking apart TP-Link repeater firmware](https://www.ctrl.blog/search?s=TP-Link%20firmware), I can note that at least TP-Link repeaters ship with a really old (4+ years out of date) DHCP client with known compatibility issues where it can’t renew it’s DHCP lease. As the repeater fails to get an IP address due to failing DHCP requests the web interface newer comes up. The repeater will still respond to ICMP pings on the IP address it is trying to renew, but SSH, telnet, app API, and web won’t work.

If you just wait for `DHCP lease time * 2` the lease will expire and the repeater will instead request a new DHCP lease without any issues; and the web interface will come back up. You can reduce the DHCP lease time on your DHCP server to reduce the time you have to wait. However, short lease times may cause other issues on your network.

This is a little too late to help you, but for anyone finding this later: just wait a while the the issue should eventually resolve itself. (Unless there is something else that is broken.) About a year ago I discovered the exact same issue affected some ASUS routers too.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to hard reset the router :/